# Getting NaN when trying to get height of body

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I'm trying to get the percentage scrolled down. So say I scroll down half the page, I'd return 50%. Now here's how I try to do that

```
var a  =  $("#container").scrollTop;
var b  =  $("body").scrollHeight - $("body").clientHeight ;
var c  =  a / b ;

console.log(c);
```

And my markup

```
<body  style="height: 100%;">
    <div id="container" style="height: 100%;">
        <!--Bunch of h1s here-->
    </div>
</body>
```

Now I run it. In the console I get `NaN`.... Even though I scroll down.... Any ideas?

Comment: Note #1 `$("#container").scrollTop()` (you're missing the parenthesis)

Comment: Have you tried printing out `b`? What's a value?

Comment: Note #2 You're calling a native JS method on a jQuery object here `$("body").scrollHeight` and here `$("body").clientHeight`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`scrolltop()` is a function, and your logic is a bit off. Try this:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        $body = $('body');

    var percent = Math.round($this.scrollTop() / ($body.height() - $this.height()) * 100);

});
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/qeqoad01/

Comment: It throws `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function ` on line 2

Comment: Not sure it's exactly accurate. At the bottom of the page and it gives me this http://i.imgur.com/JNtDRTx.png

Answer (score 0):

scrollTop is a method not an attribute.

```
<script>
        var a  =  $("#container").scrollTop();
        var b  =  document.body.scrollHeight - document.body.clientHeight ;
        var c  =  a / b ;
        console.log(c);
</script>
```

Though I don't believe it is the functionality you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use jquery it will be this way. Hope it helps

```
var a  =  $("#container").scrollTop();
var b  =  $('body').prop('scrollHeight') - $('body').prop('clientHeight') ;
var c  =  a / b ;
console.log(c);
```

This is a demo: http://jsbin.com/yejut/1/edit

Comment: Isn't it supposed to return the percent left?